# Prevent website from requesting external src

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on this website to make it work over SSL.
The thing is there is an external resource been asked with http for which apparently I do not have control, or if I have is somewhere in the PHP code.

Is there a way with jquery/javascript to prevent one website to request an external src image so that hopefully the website loads https?

Comment: Please don't link people to your live site. Questions here need to be answerable based on the content included *in the question*, they cannot depend on external links for their only example of your problem.

Comment: marking it as a duplicate was not very helpful I have to say since the tech jargon from your redirect is not exactly self-explanatory

Comment: This is a site for enthusiast and professional software developers. If you consider a technical answer to be "tech jargon", this probably isn't the right site to ask questions on.

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace http:// with // now it will load with the correct protocol.